# Checkboxes don't uncheck after toggling using jQuery in Flask app

Tags: jquery, python, checkbox, flask

I'm writing a flask app for to manage an inventory (stocks). I have a table with the stock information and 1 button (transfer). When I press transfer I want a row of checkboxes to appear in the first column together with a two buttons, one to submit the transfer and one to cancel.

When cancel is being pressed all checked checkboxes should be unchecked. 
When I wrote and tested this in a plain html file, everything worked fine. Now, when I'm trying to integrate this in a Flask app using Jinja2 templating some of my jQuery doesn't work anymore.

EDIT: here is the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/JRSl/r1oykmem/

These are the 2 parts that don't work in flask:

```
 $("#cancel-transfer").click(function(){
      if($(".case:checked").length >0) {
        $(".case").removeProp("checked");
      }
      if($("#selectAll:checked")) {
        $("#selectAll").removeProp("checked", "checked");
      }
    });
```

and this line:

```
$(".case").click(function(){

        if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
            ...
        } else {
            $("#selectAll").removeProp("checked");
        }

    });
```

Here is my **jQuery**:

```
{% block scripts %}
  {{super()}}
  <script>

    $("#transfer-btn").click(function(){
      $(".checkbox, #transfer-btn, #transfer-stocks-btn, #cancel-transfer").toggle();
    });

    $("#cancel-transfer").click(function(){
      $(".checkbox, #transfer-btn, #transfer-stocks-btn, #cancel-transfer").toggle();
      if($(".case:checked").length >0) {
        $(".case").removeProp("checked");
      }
      if($("#selectAll:checked")) {
        $("#selectAll").removeProp("checked", "checked");
      }
    });

    $(function(){

    // add multiple select / deselect functionality
    $("#selectAll").click(function () {
          $('.case').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });

    // if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
    // and viceversa
    $(".case").click(function(){

        if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
            $("#selectAll").prop("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $("#selectAll").removeProp("checked");
        }

    });
  });
  </script>
  <script type=text/javascript src="/static/jquery.min.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

I added these **styles**:

```
{% block styles %}
  {{super()}}
  <style>
    .checkbox {
      display: none;
      margin: 0;
    }

    #transfer-stocks-btn, #cancel-transfer {
      display:none;
    }

  </style>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is the **Jinja2 template**:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block page_content %}

  <div>
    {% if user == current_user %}

      <button class="btn btn-default" id="transfer-btn">
        Transfer
      </button>

      <button class="btn btn-default" id="transfer-stocks-btn">
        Transfer stocks
      </button>

      <button class="btn btn-default" id="cancel-transfer">
        Cancel
      </button>

    {% endif %}

  <div>
    <table class="table table-hover  table-condensed">
       <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>
             <div class="checkbox">
               <label><input type="checkbox" id="selectAll"/>&nbsp;</label>
             </div>
           </th>
           <th>Stock ID</th>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>vendor Id</th>
           <th>Comments</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         {% for stock in stocks %}
         <tr>
           <td>
             <div class="checkbox">
               <label><input type="checkbox" class="case" />&nbsp;</label>
             </div>
           </td>
           <td>{{ stock.id }} </td>
           <td>{{ stock.name }}</td>
           <td>{{ stock.vendor}}</td>
           <td>{{ stock.comment }} </td>
         </tr>
         {% endfor %}
       </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

{% endblock %}

Thank you very much for the assistance!

Comment: could you make a fiddle with this code please?

Comment: Fiddle included in the EDIT.

Comment: you have to use $("input[class^='case']").prop('checked', false); to uncheck all inputs see: https://jsfiddle.net/sno83agc/

Comment: Thanks! I included this change and a similar one and that works. I also found out that in earlier versions of jQuery the removeProp("checked") does work. any thoughts on that?